# Vim to behave like nvi when opening line in empty buffer

Tags: buffers, nvi

I want to *Vim* to behave like *nvi* when opening a in an empty buffer.

This is an empty buffer:

```
----------------------------------------
~
~
~
~
----------------------------------------
```

After typing `oHello, world!<esc>` I want to get this result (which is how it behaves in the original *Vi*):

```
----------------------------------------
Hello, world!
~
~
~
----------------------------------------
```

In *Vim* i get this result instead (notice extra blank line):

```
----------------------------------------

Hello, world!
~
~
----------------------------------------
```

Is there any way I can get *Vim* to behave like *nvi* when opening new lines in an empty buffer?

I think the *nvi* behavior is much more useful when I want to type something like `8oEight long lines...<esc>` in an empty buffer. Then I don't have to remove the extra blank line that *Vim* always creates when doing that.

Comment: The `o` in Vi (050325) behaves just like the `o` in Vim (7.4.2196) and in doing so adheres to the behavior specified in the POSIX standard. You should investigate why your vi doesn't work correctly instead of forcing your Vim to behave incorrectly.

Comment: Why not use `i` instead of `o`? I agree with @romainl, the "original vi" behaviour of `o` seems very strange. What `vi` are you using where you see this behaviour?

Comment: You can always use `8` `O` `Eight long lines...<esc>` instead (using capital o)

Comment: nvi behaves the same. there does not seem to be a 'cpo' setting to change that behaviour. However you could simply map it like this possibly: `:nnoremap <expr> o line('$')==1 && empty(getline(1))?'i':'o'`

Comment: The behavior described was from nvi which I assumed was the behavior of original vi.

Comment: and a mapping does not work for you?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The "strangeness" is the result of an (invisible, except for variants that show a ~ at the top of the screen in this case) distinction between an empty file and a file consisting of a single blank line.